# Weird overlap on only right side of child div from parent div when child width set to 100%

Tags: css

I have a parent div and child `div`. The child div width set to 100%.

Both have borders on them of 2px.

What is strange is the left edge of the child div shows up while the right edge seems to be covered up by the parent `div`.

Changing margin on child div or padding on parent div doesn't seem to do the trick.

Resizing child width to something lower than 100% seems to work but don't want to do that and not sure why it is happening?

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Boovius/8armB/2/

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id='parent'>
        <div class='child'></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent {
    height: 550px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid 
    overflow: scroll;
}
.child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Border is included in width calculations by default. Change (or simply remove) your width or your box-sizing mode:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8armB/3/

```
.child {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: great answer - box-sizing is a neat tip

Answer (score 1):

If you don't change the display-property, divs are rendered as block elements and therefore always fill the whole width of their parent elements. Depends on how realistic you example is, but in that case just remove the width on the child `div`.

http://jsfiddle.net/8armB/4/